# Background job using parse-server & Heroku Scheduler

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, heroku, parse-platform

Using parse-server and heroku for my Android application. Want to create background jobs, like the ones offered by Parse.com earlier, but can't seem to make it work. 
In the parser-server-example folder, I have added a jobs.js file containing this:

```
var Parse = require('parse/node');
Parse.initialize('my_app_id');
Parse.serverURL = 'https://random-name.herokuapp.com/parse';

function saveSomething(){
var obj = new Parse.Object('my_class', 'random');
obj.save(null, {
    success: function(place){
        console.log("Success!!");
    },
    error: function(place, error){
        console.log("Fail: " + error.message);
    }
});
}

function sayHello() {
console.log('Hello');
}

sayHello();
saveSomething();
```

sayHello() runs fine, but saveSomething() get "error: unauthorized" message when i run: heroku run node jobs.js . 
So I have 2 questions.

1.Is this det correct way to create a background job using parse-server & heroku?

2.Anything wrong with the "jobs.js" code/something that should be done differently in general to accomplish the background job task?

(Tried adding javascript-key to the Parse.initialize('app-id', 'javascript-key'); without any luck)

Comment: If anyone is interested I wrote an article how to get background jobs with using `kue`: https://andreygordeev.com/2016/08/04/parse-background-jobs-on-parse-server.html

Answer (score 6):

The solutions was to add "Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();" after the line "Parse.serverURL = 'https://random-name.herokuapp.com/parse', and add the apps master key in the "Parse.initialize('my_app_id', 'js-key', 'master-key'); to get the correct authorisation.

```
var Parse = require('parse/node');
Parse.initialize('app-id', 'js-key','master-key');
Parse.serverURL = 'https://random-name.herokuapp.com/parse/';
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

function saveSomething(){
var MyClass = Parse.Object.extend("MyClass");
var myclass = new MyClass();
myclass.set("columnName", "value");
myclass.save({
    success: function(place){
        console.log("Success!!");
    },
    error: function(place, error){
        console.log("Fail: " + error.message);
    }
});
}

saveSomething();
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: and did you succeed to make it works with heroku scheduler ? My function works with heroku run node jobs.js --app appName. Now I would like to use it with Heroku Scheduler, can you help me ? What I've to write on this line "$" ?

Comment: You just have to write "node jobs.js" on the $ line, like you would run it locally, since you are basically just running it on another machine. Then you can just set your frequency, and then it will work.

Comment: @Slagathor I'm planing to do background task on Heroku similar to this question. What's the command to set frequency of my task say like once per hour?

Comment: @Geeroz If you are using the Heroku Scheduler you can just set a time interval in your Heroku Dashboard. Just push Heroku Scheduler in your dashboard, then hit "edit", and then select "hourly" in the drop down menu.