# Scheduled jobs on Heroku, coming from Parse.com, no callbacks fired

Tags: node.js, heroku, parse-platform, promise, scheduled-tasks

We're moving from parse.com to Heroku and having issues with getting the scheduled jobs to run using Heroku Scheduler.

Using `heroku run node cloud/scheduled.js` I try to run the below file. However, neither the `success` callback or the `error` callback is fired. Anybody have any clue why this is happening?

```
var Parse = require('parse/node');
Parse.initialize(
    '<app-id>',
    '<js-key>',
    '<masterkey>'
);
Parse.serverURL = 'https://hang-app-dev.herokuapp.com/parse';
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

function findSomething(){
    var userObject = Parse.Object.extend("User");
    var query = new Parse.Query(userObject);
    query.include("firstName");
    query.equalTo("verifiedPhone", true);
    query.find({
        success: function(results){
            console.log("Success!!");
        },
        error: function(results, error){
            console.log("Fail: " + error.message);
        }
    });
}

findSomething();

process.exit();
```

Link to [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35523542/background-job-using-parse-server-heroku-scheduler): but the solution doesn't seem to work in our setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometime back I have tried running the parse cloud jobs using Heroku Scheduler.
I simply converted Parse.Cloud.job to Parse.Cloud.define and used curl script to run the cloud function from heroku scheduler.
Don't know if this is a good solution though.